# Netbeans debugger stops at Class.java.getDeclaredConstructors

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I'm trying to debug web application in netbeans 7.2.1 with glassfish server 3.1. Debugging worked fine previously.

But Netbeans debugger suddenly started to print this message:

```
Thread admin-thread-pool-4848(2) stopped at Class.java.getDeclaredConstructors0.
```

Debugger stops at that line as if there was a breakpoint there and also at this line:

```
 res = Reflection.filterFields(this, getDeclaredFields0(publicOnly));
 in method private Field[] privateGetDeclaredFields(boolean publicOnly)
```

If I press a button to continue  it stops again at same point for several times and deploying  continues for a long time until it fails with message

```
Deployment error: Deployment timeout has exceeded.
```

I know it's not much information, but maybe someone has a hint what it could be related to?

Comment: I had the same issue sometime ago (SpringSource + tomcat7), the solution was to clean-up all breakpoints "Run -> Remove All Breakpoints..."

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem using Netbeans8, Glasshfish 4.0 and JavaEE JAX-RS. The problem was a breakpoint placed inside a lib that was part of a previous project I was working on.

Solved it by clearing/deleting all breakpoints. To do so, on the Netbeans top bar:  window -> debugging -> breakpoints -> and then disable them or right click and delete all of them.